# webapp or django, which framework to opt for on google app engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, frameworks

Im currently learning about Google App Engine and how it can be used to develop web apps. I have some knowledge of Django too.
What is the best way to go for building an app on Google App Engine,should i use the default webapp framework or use Django ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: Kind of depends on what kind of web app you are going to build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on your project

you can use both , but i prefer webapp cause its simple for me

Google App Engine SDK used to ship with Django 0.96 not the latest version

but there is a project called http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel forked of the latest version of Django

here is an article to run native django apps on GAE
http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/01/Native-Django-on-App-Engine